# Product and Versions are not displayed when creating new test plan in Kiwi TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm running Kiwi TCMS in Windows 10 home as a docker container and I'm using docker tool box. Kiwi web is up in 192.168.99.100 and a super user is also created.

But products and version are not available when creating test plans
[image: screenshot attached here]
 Can someone help me on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "products and version are not available" ? Post a screenshot.

Comment: i posted a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have any products in the database. Why don't you click the + button and add some ?

Comment: Products in the database should come with the installation right ? Or else should we add products ?

Comment: How do you expect the software to know what products exists in your company? Just define them when necessary.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you for your help!